# How to search an item between two number range in Elastic Search

Tags: angular, typescript, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-plugin, elasticsearch-dsl

We have two fields startid and endid in Elastic Search, For example **startid - 3061410 and endid - 3061450**. Now if i Enter any Number between 3061410 and 3061450, the query should fetch that item. Click here for The snapshot of the elastic index :-
[Elastic index snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OIcp4.png)

Expected result snapshot:
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Br3nW.png)

I Tried the following Query but did not get the expected result :

```
{ "range": { "startid": { "gte": parseInt(this.selectedOP_no),"lte":+parseInt(this.selectedOP_no)+40 } } }
```

**Where this.selectedOP_no is the number between startid and endid like 3061411**

Answer (score 0):

Since you have two fields, you need to have two conditions, one on each field, like this:

```
{ 
   "bool": {
      "filter": [
         {
            "range": { 
              "endid": { 
                 "gte": parseInt(this.selectedOP_no) + 40 
              } 
            } 
         },
         {
            "range": { 
              "startid": { 
                 "lte":+parseInt(this.selectedOP_no)
              } 
            } 
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Comment: It's not working. Suppose `selectedOP_no = 3061411` then the **startid** condition return false.so I modified the query like ` { 
      "bool": {
         "filter": [
            {
               "range": { 
                 "endid": { 
                    "gte": this.selectedOP_no 
                 } 
               } 
            },
            {
               "range": { 
                 "startid": { 
                    "lte":this.selectedOP_no  
                 } 
               } 
            }
         ]
      }
   }`  and now it seems working at my end.

Comment: Oh yes, indeed, the fields need to be switched, I've updated my answer